# Parallel optimization - multithreading performance hit

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I want to run several runs of simulated annealing with different parameters many times to tune the parameters. It seemed like this would be an obvious use case for multiple threads since each run might take several seconds for a large number of iterations and can do its work independently of the others. A sketch of the relevant portion of the code is:

```
// I have some vector 'results' with 4 elements that will hold the
// optimization results (call this result_t) and a vector 'probs' of 
// 4 functors of type 'prob_t'. 'cost_t' is some integral type.

auto driver = [=] (result_t& r, prob_t p) 
{ r = genericSimulatedAnneal<result_t, cost_t, prob_t> 
        (guess, params, p); };

std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int t_num = 0; t_num < 4; ++t_num) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(driver, std::ref(results[t_num]),
                                  probs[t_num]));
}

for (auto& t: threads) t.join();
```

The signature of `genericSimulatedAnneal` is

```
template<class solution_t, class cost_t, class acceptance_p>
genericSimulatedAnneal(const solution_t&, 
                       const GenSimAnnealParams<solution_t,cost_t>&,
                       const acceptance_p&);
```

The problem is that when I run the 4 cases in parallel this way, it actually ends up taking twice as much CPU time per iteration as running them sequentially. My question is, where is the performance hit coming from? The driver lambda copies the guess and parameters, so threads should each be getting their own copy, and each thread's work is done entirely internally and only returned when the annealing finishes. I can't see why this wouldn't be (almost) a 4 times speedup since the vast majority of the program's work should be private to each thread.

Comment: You are creating a vector of four "not a thread" threads, then pushing another four running threads into the vector, then trying to join them all, including  the non-joinable threads.

Comment: Oops, that's a mistake in how I typed up the code here; I did it from memory. That's not in the original or it wouldn't run. I'll edit to fix.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a no-counterfeit policy. We only want to see the original code, no cheap copies, imitations, reproductions from memory or off-brand generics.

Comment: How many cores does your machine have?

Comment: I have 8 cores; that's not the issue.

Comment: And I've done multithreading of things like multiplying large sparse matrices before with good success and found 4 threads to be about the sweet spot before OS overhead kills any gains.

Comment: Are your four threads operating on overlapping data? I'm guessing they're contending.

Comment: This could be because the threads are stepping on each other's cache lines (contention), they're lined up waiting for a lock (allocating memory?) or your simulator uses lots of memory and the memory access is maxed, just to name a few reasons.